# Creating and Manipulating an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

I need to create array by parsing the following string, then I need to store that array in another array. After which I'll need to be able to access the values using the containing array as an index. I have many lines that look like the following:

```
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="2">
```

so far, my code is able to identify the numbers I'm looking for, but I'm unfamiliar with both power shell's way of handling / accessing arrays and regex. I need to store each number in an array contained by an array. I'd really appreciate some guidance on this one.

```
foreach ($line in $data){
    if ($line -like "*RowNumber*" -and $line -like "*ColumnNumber*") 
    {
        $LineSplit = $line.Split('" ')
        $valuelocation = [regex]::Matches($LineSplit, '"(.*?)"')  

        write-host "found line" $line
        write-host "Cut lines into" $LineSplit
        write-host "Match Data is" $valuelocation[0, 0]
   }
}
```

Comment: The line you want to parse looks like XML. If that's the case you should use a proper XML parser.

Comment: Angers is right that you should treat this as XML, but if you have to use regex, then you can match and extract the numbers in one go, something like this: `$line -match '.*RowNumber="(?<row>\d+)" ColumnNumber="(?<col>\d+)"\>$'`.  The numbers are then available later with: `$matches.row` and `$matches.col`

Comment: Unfortunately, the XML data I'm parsing is huge and improperly formatted so using a prebuilt parser hasn't been an option. The regex you're showing me here looks good, but could you tell me if there's a way for me to store the result in an array? I would want the values to be stored as standalone variables.

Comment: Formatting shouldn't be an issue. Did you mean that the XML is invalid? That would best be fixed at the source generating the XML. I realize that isn't always an option, though.